# Using new with Scala final case class

Tags: class, scala, new-operator, case, final

In Chapter 22 of "Programming in Scala" book, the `::` class (cons) is defined as

```
final case class ::[T](hd: T, tl: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  //...
}
```

The `::` method in class `List` is defined as follows:

```
def ::[U >: T](x: U): List[U] = new scala.::(x, this)
```

Why is the `new` required to create an instance of the `final`**`case`**`class ::`? Is this purely for disambiguation?

Comment: final only means that the class can not be extended, it has nothing to do with instance creation :-). Case class is basically a class that can be compared in a 'match case' block.

Answer (score 7):

With case classes you automatically get a companion object whose `apply` method calls the constructor, in the same way as you can do this with an ordinary class:

```
class Foo(val value: Int) 
object Foo { def apply(value: Int) = new Foo(value) }

val x = new Foo(42)  //
val y = Foo(42)      // both work the same
```

You can instantiate case classes with `new` if you want to. It might in theory be slightly faster because it doesn't have to go via the companion object's `apply` method, but I tried a quick benchmark and saw absolutely no difference in performance, so I guess it's optimised by the compiler, or just an immeasurably small difference compared to the actual construction.

So I don't think the `new` in the example you give has any significance and could just as well have been left out.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct; the `new` is not mandatory.  They could have defined the instance method `List#::` like this just as well:

```
def ::[U >: T](x: U): List[U] = scala.::(x, this)
```

(Note that we have:

```
type :: = collection.immutable.::
val  :: = collection.immutable.::
```

defined in the `scala` package object; the first is why your `new scala.::(x, this)` works, and the second is why my `scala.::(x, this)` works.)

[The form the library uses](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L66) calls the constructor directly, as yours does.  The alternative calls the `apply` method of the synthetic companion object generated for the `::` case class, which simply calls the constructor anyway.  Perhaps calling the constructor was deemed clearer, or more efficient?  (Efficiency gains should be close to nothing, though, since if the compiler doesn't inline the call to `apply`, the JVM will.)  I suppose the most compact form:

```
def ::[U >: T](x: U) = ::(x, this)
```

could be mistaken for some wacky (i.e., impossible) sort of recursive invocation, and at any rate blurs the distinction between the class called `::` and the `List` method called `::`, which Prof. Odersky takes pains to keep separate in order to maximize reader comprehension.

Hope this helps.